# PHP INSERT to hosting database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this PHP code that inserts id, firstname and lastname:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'happy', '***');
$db   = mysql_select_db('dbtest');


$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbltry (firstname, lastname) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname')");
?>
```

And I have this HTML with AJAX:

```
<script>
function save(){
var xmlhttp;

         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
         else
         {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }


        xmlhttp.open("POST", " **url** ", true);
        console.log("added");
        xmlhttp.send();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {

             }
         }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
<button onclick="save()">Save</button>
</body>
```

This two are working fine, it insert a new row in database, but the only data that is inserted is the id on id column and column firstname and lastname is blank.

Can someone tell what am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you correct this spelling $fisrtname to $firstname

Comment: Side note: Your PHP script has an open invitation for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: also please try shifting from mysql* extensions to PDO as mysql* extensions are deprecated officially

Comment: your javascript function `save` needs to know what data to send (your inputs) on the post request.

Comment: It could be the typo in your code; you had **VALUES('$fisrtname', '$lastname')** instead of **VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname')** . See if that fixes it.

Comment: I fixed it in my PHP but still inserts blank

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
function save(){
 var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
 var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
 var data = "firstname="+fname+"&lastname="+lname;  
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        
        }
      }
     
    xmlhttp.open("POST","url?"+data,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

your test file should be like

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'happy', '***');
$db   = mysql_select_db('dbtest');


$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbltry (firstname, lastname) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname')");
?>
```

Instead of using old xmlhttp its better to use [jQuery.Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), Also mysql functions are deprecated use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo_mysql).

You should use any mysql escape function for security.

Hope it helps..

Comment: I tried this one but firstname and lastname is still blank and no alert.
I'm not sure if I did it right like this: `xmlhttp.open("GET","http://url.com/dir/testing.php?"+data,true);`
And this one here:
`var data = "firstname="+fname+"&lastname="+lname;`
because the lastname has '&' and firstname don't have.

Comment: its query string param then entire url will be like http://url.com/dir/testing.php?firstname=your name&lastname=your name , second one required & check my updated code your firstname in query has a typo(spell issue).

Comment: Try my code exactly. alert() dont have any data bcoz your nothing output from that page.

Comment: It's still not inserting firstname and lastname only id. I'll try something more and will get back here. Thank you so much my friend for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
function save(){
var xmlhttp;

var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
 var lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;

var data = {firstname:fname,lastname:lname};
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
         {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
         else
         {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }


        xmlhttp.open("POST", " **url** ", true);
        console.log("added");
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.send(data);

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
         {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {

             }
         }
}
```

Comment: Tried this one but still blank.